# Perl Mojolicious: chaining Promises

Tags: perl, promise, concurrency, mojolicious

In a Mojolicious Controller I'd like to chain 2 sets of Promises. The first (e.g. `delDB1` & `delDB2`) deletes from a source, and when done, the second set (e.g. `addBD1` & `addDB2`) adds to the source.

Do you add another `then`? And if so, how do I pass the new set of Promises?

It doesn't seem right to nest the call inside.

```perl
my @promise;
foreach my $code (\&delDB1, \&delDB2) {
  my $prom = Mojo::Promise->new;
  Mojo::IOLoop->subprocess(
    sub {
      return $code->($number);
    },
    sub {
      my ($subprocess, $err, @res) = @_;
      return $prom->reject($err) if $err;
      $prom->resolve(@res);
    },
  );
  push @promise, $prom;
}

Mojo::IOLoop->start unless Mojo::IOLoop->is_running;
Mojo::Promise->all(@promise)
  ->then(
  sub {
    my ($delDB1response, $delDB2response) = map {$_->[0]} @_;
    ### Nest a call for another set of promises?
    $app->render(openapi=>{messages=>"success"});
  })->catch(
    sub ($err) {
    warn "### Something went wrong: $err";
  })->wait;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is unclear. I think you want the following:

1. Try,

   1. Start `delDB1`.
   2. Start `delDB2`.
   3. Wait for both to complete.
   4. Start `addDB1`.
   5. Start `addDB2`.
   6. Wait for both to complete.
   7. Render a successful response.
2. Catch,

   1. Render a failure response.

This can be achieved using the following:

```perl
Mojo::Promise
->all( delDB1_async(), delDB2_async() )
->then(sub {
   return Mojo::Promise->all( addDB1_async(), addDB2_async() );
})
->then(sub {
   # Render successful response here...
})
->catch(sub {
   # Render failure response here...
})
->wait;
```

In the above, `_async` functions are expected to return a promise.

If we give the promises names for the sake of discussion, the code becomes

```perl
my $promise1 = delDB1_async();
my $promise2 = delDB2_async();

my $promise3 = Mojo::Promise->all( $promise1, $promise2 );
my $promise4 = $promise3->then(sub {
   my $promise5 = addDB1_async();
   my $promise6 = addDB2_async();

   my $promise7 = Mojo::Promise->all( $promise5, $promise6 );

   return $promise7;
});

my $promise8 = $promise4->then(sub {
   # Render successful response here...
});

my $promise9 = $promise8->catch(sub {
   # Render failure response here...
});

$promise9->wait;
```

The key part is that `$promise4` becomes fulfilled when `$promise7` becomes fulfilled, and with the same value.

---

But let's say you wanted

1. Try,

   1. Start:

      1. Start `delDB1`.
      2. Wait for it to complete.
      3. Start `addDB1`.
      4. Wait for it to complete.
   2. Start:

      1. Start `delDB2`.
      2. Wait for it to complete.
      3. Start `addDB2`.
      4. Wait for it to complete.
   3. Wait for both to complete.
   4. Render a successful response.
2. Catch,

   1. Render a failure response.

This can be achieved using the following:

```perl
Mojo::Promise
->all(
    delDB1_async()->then(sub { return addDB1_async() }),
    delDB2_async()->then(sub { return addDB2_async() }),
)
->then(sub {
   # Render successful response here...
})
->catch(sub {
   # Render failure response here...
})
->wait;
```

---

Example `delDB1_async`:

```perl
sub delDB1_async {
   return Mojo::Promise->new(sub {
      my ( $resolve, $reject ) = @_;
      Mojo::IOLoop->subprocess(
         sub {
            ...
         },
         sub {
            my ( $subprocess, $err, @res ) = @_;
            $reject->( $err ) if $err;
            $resolve->( @res );
         }
      );
  });
}
```

Passing a sub to `->new` is better because exceptions from that code result in in the promise getting rejected. This is great if the code accidentally throws an exception.

...except Mojo::Promise violates the spec to which it claims to abide. So you're currently screwed if the code accidentally throws an exception.